# Creating local storage data when first loading an Ionic 3 app onto a mobile device

Tags: ionic3, persistence

I am writing an Ionic 3 app that needs to create a table of data when the app first runs after being installed.

During the app's use data will be changed in the table of data depending on what the user does whilst using the app.

How can I create a data table in local storage on the device which will persist until the app is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite storage for a data table structure or Native Storage from ionic 3 native doc(Key and value structure) or simple localstorage

Comment: The question is how is it done when first running the app.

Comment: create a sqlite db from app.component.ts which is also a entry point inside platform.ready function

Comment: You could query first to see if the sqlite.db exists, and if not, then create it and populate the default data.